# How to record a bar position ID of a bar that had a buy signal on it

Tags: pine-script

I'm still a newbie at pine script,
I have an indicator in version 5, which places a buy arrow marker at a bar that meets my criteria to buy at that point. I then have some criteria that place a sell arrow at a bar that meets those.
I would like to keep track of the buy bar id, so I could add a condition to my sell criteria if the current price drops below the buy price.
I am not using Trading View to trade, just to give me these marks.
A follow up question: how could I get the exact price and record it, at which my buy bar generated the buy signal, as obviously it may have been a long bar, and at some point in it my conditions for buy signal were met. In this way I could just use the drop in price from my buy signal as one of the  conditions to sell.

Hope this makes sense, and thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track the entry price you can use the following built in:

```
strategy.position_avg_price
```

which will return the price that the current order filled at.

Cheers and best of luck